# Regex that will extract one to four numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I'm making a small tool that needs to extract build numbers from a text file. I've managed to get my regex to extract lines that look like this:

```
"dolphin-master-4.0-1-x64.7z"
"dolphin-master-4.0-10-x64.7z"
"dolphin-master-4.0-200-x64.7z"
"dolphin-master-4.0-3000-x64.7z"
```

I'd like to extract the build number from these lines. Either "4.0-xxxx" or just "xxxx"

The tricky part I ran into is when I realized the build numbers would be anywhere from one to four numbers. Can I get some help here?

Comment: It is just between `dolphin-master-` and `-x64.7z`

Comment: You should be able to do something along the lines of `[0-9]{1,4}`. This will match a number up to 4 times. **Edit:** actually, I guess this would also match the "6" the "4" and the "7" in "x64" and "7z" as well. So this might not work so well.

Comment: This should help: xxxx = \d{1,4}

Comment: `([\d]{1,4})` or `[0-9]{1,4}` will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the pattern `\d{1,4}` to match 1-4 numbers - e.g. `4\.0\.\d{1,4}` or `4\.0\.(\d{1,4})`. You can find more information about the .NET regex syntax [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I didn't know I could do a range of number lengths.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=4\.0-)(\d{1,4})(?=-)` will match exactly what's in between `4.0-` and `-` and only if it's 1 to 4 digits.

Comment: You can simplify: `(4\.0-)(\d{1,4})(-)` and select only the Groups[1] but it's less precise.